# Simple excel find and replace for formulas

Tags: excel, replace

I have numerous cells all over the place on a worksheet that look like `=((E9-E8)/E8)`. I want to use the first two values to go into this new formula, `(EXP((LN(E9/E8)/14.32))-1)`.

How can I change them all to the new formula in one fell swoop?

Comment: All over the place means that there were three different columns in which the formula would occur for a total of 31 times. I ended up switching to R1C1 since the structure was the same in every case. See my answer.

Comment: My product, FormulaDesk has a formula refactoring feature, that enables exactly this. Define a pattern to find, with placeholders, then define output text, using the variables from the placeholders. See: http://www.formuladesk.com (I haven't added this as an answer, as I don't want to self-promote, but it does answer your question perfectly, I think. If someone else wants to add this as an answer then please do)

Answer (score 17):

If the formulas are identical you can use Find and Replace with `Match entire cell contents` checked and `Look in: Formulas`. Select the range, go into Find and Replace, make your entries and `Replace All.

[image]

Or do you mean that there are several formulas with this same form, but different cell references? If so, then one way to go is a regular expression match and replace. Regular expressions are not built into Excel (or VBA), but can be accessed via Microsoft's VBScript Regular Expressions library.

The following function provides the necessary match and replace capability. It can be used in a subroutine that would identify cells with formulas in the specified range and use the formulas as inputs to the function. For formulas strings that match the pattern you are looking for, the function will produce the replacement formula, which could then be written back to the worksheet.

```
Function RegexFormulaReplace(formula As String)
    Dim regex As New RegExp
    regex.Pattern = "=\(\(([A-Z]+\d+)-([A-Z]+\d+)\)/([A-Z]+\d+)\)"
'   Test if a match is found
    If regex.Test(formula) = True Then
        RegexFormulaReplace = regex.Replace(formula, "=(EXP((LN($1/$2)/14.32))-1")
    Else
        RegexFormulaReplace = CVErr(xlErrValue)
    End If
    Set regex = Nothing
End Function
```

In order for the function to work, you would need to add a reference to the Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5 library. From the `Developer` tab of the main ribbon, select `VBA` and then `References` from the main toolbar. Scroll down to find the reference to the library and check the box next to it.

Comment: Yes there are several formulas with the same form but different cell references.

Answer (score 7):

It turns out that the solution was to switch to R1C1 Cell Reference. My worksheet was structured in such a way that every formula had the same structure just different references. Luck though, they were always positioned the same way

```
=((E9-E8)/E8)
```

became

```
=((R[-1]C-R[-2]C)/R[-2]C)
```

and

```
(EXP((LN(E9/E8)/14.32))-1)
```

became

```
=(EXP((LN(R[-1]C/R[-2]C)/14.32))-1)
```

In R1C1 Reference, every formula was identical so the find and replace required no wildcards. Thank you to those who answered!

Answer (score 3):

The way I typically handle this is with a second piece of software. 
For Windows I use Notepad++, for OS X I use Sublime Text 2.

1. In Excel, hit Control + ~ (OS X)
2. Excel will convert all values to their formula version
3. CMD + A (I usually do this twice) to select the entire sheet
4. Copy all contents and paste them into Notepad++/Sublime Text 2
5. Find / Replace your formula contents here
6. Copy the contents and paste back into Excel, confirming any issues about cell size differences
7. Control + ~ to switch back to values mode

Answer (score 1):

Use the find and replace command accessible through ctrl+h, make sure you are searching through the functions of the cells. You can then wildcards to accommodate any deviations of the formula. * for # wildcards, ? for charcter wildcards, and ~? or ~* to search for ? or *.

Comment: I'm new to this so I'm not quite sure how that works. How would I represent the formulas I put in my question using wildcards? Again, I have like 30 formulas that look like that all with different references that I want to change to look like the second formula.

Comment: Changing all the cell references to wildcards would look like the following;   

Find: =((?*-?*)/?*)      
Replace: =(EXP((LN(?*/?*)/14.32))-1)   If you require more wildcards I hope this will serve as a good example for you.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. Fortunately, I was able to resolve the issue a different way. See my answer if you're curious

Answer (score 0):

You can also click on the Formulas tab in Excel and select Show Formulas, then use the regular "Find" and "Replace" function. This should not affect the rest of your formula.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. I was able to change over 300 reference in numerous formulas in a worksheet in one replace all command.