# EXCEL Changing One Specific Thing in a Formula

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet full of references, pretty much every permutation you can imagine.

EX:
='January Scorecard'!F7 
='February Scorecard'!F7 

='March Scorecard'!H7 
='April Scorecard'!H7

I want to be able to change specific things of the formula across an entire row or column. So if I need to change a row where all of the references currently point to 'H7', I want to be able to quickly change all of them to 'F31' or another arbitrary cell value.

What are quick ways to change cells specifically while keeping the reference sheets the same?

Comment: How about Find/Replace

Comment: Possibly relevant: [find and replace within fomulae](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17847919/simple-excel-find-and-replace-for-formulas)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the INDIRECT function. This takes a cell reference which contains text representing a cell address, and converts it into that cell address. So if cell A1 had the text "H7", then your example cells would now have

=INDIRECT("'March Scorecard'!" & A1)

whcih would firstly convert to  "'March Scorecard'!H7 " and then the indirect would convert it to ='March Scorecard'!H7

Comment: Nooooo! Indirect is volatile and should be avoided, because it will trigger a recalculation of the whole workbook when ANY cell is edited. If you want to tackle this with formulas, use Index instead.